# PyQt5 QWebEngineView causes blurry/fuzzy scaling issue

Tags: python, qt, qt5, pyqt5

When a `QWebEngineView` is added to the window, it causes strange scaling issues across the entire window. This is seen with the latest version of PyQt5 from pip (PyQt5=5.9, Qt5=5.9.1), Python 3.6, and Windows 10. For example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
#
class WebViewer(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        page = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage(self)
        self.setPage(page)
        self.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl('http://apple.com'))
    #
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    appQT = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    #
    main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(None)
    window_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(main_widget)
    #
    window_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QTextEdit("1. abc<br/>2. def<br/>3. ghi", main_widget))
    ####window_layout.addWidget(WebViewer(main_widget))
    #
    main_widget.show()
    appQT.exec_()
#
```

Results in:

[image: Before]

If I uncomment the `window_layout.addWidget(WebViewer(main_widget))` line, I get:

[image]

The mouse position also does not correspond with what Qt thinks it's clicking on. Is this a bug in Qt5, or is there some dpi/scaling setting I should change? This is also seen with PyQt5.7.1 and PyQt5.8. This doesn't occur with a `QWebView` in older versions of PyQt5.

Comment: It seems that it is a bug of QWebEngineView, some time ago a user had the same problem but in Windows, report it to pyqt, since the solution that obtained was that he used showFullScreen instead of show. This problem is not observed in Linux.

Comment: This is the question that I am telling you about: [PyQt WebEngineView interferes with MainMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45314416/pyqt-webengineview-interferes-with-mainmenu)

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks! That's definitely the same problem, I don't know how I missed that in my search. I'll send it off to pyqt.