# PyQt5: QWebEngineView Distortion on Resize

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I have a python application that simply displays given html, with the following code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class IFace(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 1000, 500)
        self.view = WebView(self)
        self.setLayout(QGridLayout(self))
        self.layout().addWidget(self.view, 0, 0)
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

class WebView(QWebEngineView):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setHtml("""<html><head></head><body><center>
<h1>Hi!</h1>
<h1>Hi!</h1>
<h1>Hi!</h1>
</body></html>""")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = IFace()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The html is displayed correctly at first, but resizing the window vertically will cause the displayed webpage to 'stretch' downwards, distorting the text:

Before resizing:
[image: Unstretched WebEngineView]

After resizing:
[image: Stretched WebEngineView]

Note how the the text is taller, but not wider.  The text also moves downwards as the window is shrunk vertically.

When I place another widget to the left of the `QWebEngineView`, such as a `QLabel`, the distortion affects the `QLabel` as well.  If I do not include the `QWebEngineView`, the `QLabel` is not distorted.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

It appears to have something to do with the instantiation of a `QWebEngineView` that has the window as a parent, as the effect persists when the `QWebEngineView` is only created not placed, and the effect does not remain when the `QWebEngineView` is instantiated by `QWebEngineView()` without the widget as a parent.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (using qt-5.10.1 on linux).

Comment: Thanks for the data.  I have the same version (uninstalled and reinstalled to be safe) on a Windows 10 laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred due to outdated drivers.  I found the solution (also on stackoverflow) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45314416/pyqt-webengineview-interferes-with-mainmenu), though it was to a slightly different problem (widgets being hidden beneath the title bar, not distortion of the QWebEngineView).

I updated my Intel(R) HD Graphics driver (forwards, unlike the listed answer in the link) and the issue went away.